# JavaScript y Información en .YAML, "undefined"

Tags: javascript, yaml

expongo mi problema. Estoy intentando hacer una peticion para leer un .YAML, todo funciona menos cuando intento cambiar uno de los valores de la request por los datos introducidos por un usuarios, dejo unos ejemplos aqui:

**CODIGO:**

```
//Cargando el .YAML
            const raw = fs.readFileSync("../plugins/PermaDeathCore/jugadores.yml");
            const data = YAML.safeLoad(raw);

            // Recogiendo el INPUT de los usuarios [Argumentos]
            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const PrimerArgumento = args[1]

            //Consulta al .YAML directamente (FUNCIONA ✅)
            console.log(data.Players.Miguel)

            // Consulta al .YAML pasando el argumento (NO FUNCIONA❌)
            console.log(data.Players.PrimerArgumento)
```

**RESPUESTA:**

```
{ HP: 0, banCause: 'Vacío', banTime: '01:39:57', banDay: '2020-06-30' }

undefined
```

El primer console.log ha funcionado pero el segundo que es exactamente lo mismo no funciona, el input de un usario por ejemplo puede ser "Miguel" y en teoria si no voy mal quedaria data.Players.Miguel, pero responde con undefined. Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

Comment: Saludos. Creo lo que esta ocurriendo es tu tratamiendo de datos. ¿Existe en `data.Players` `PrimerArgumento`? ¿Será que realmente debes usar `console.log(PrimerArgumento)` y no `console.log(data.Players.PrimerArgumento)`?

Comment: El tema es que necesito pasar ese valor con argumento para que los usuarios de un discord al pasar un argumento en un comando puedan sacar la información del jugador que quieran, ejemplo:

`/player Paco`

Esto internamente seria `data.Players.PrimerArgumento` = `data.Players.Paco`

Comment: ¿Puedes poner lo que sale con `console.log(PrimerArgumento)` y con `console.log(data.Players[PrimerArgumento])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en la forma de hacer la peticion, para usar una variable como identificador debia pasarla con " [ ] ", espero que el error que tube ayude a alguien en un futuro.

**Antes (mal)**

```
const PrimerArgument = "Miguel"
console.log(data.Players.PrimerArgumento)
```

**Ahora (Bien)**

```
const PrimerArgument = "Miguel"
console.log(data.Players[PrimerArgumento])
```